# eclipse rap socket programming

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

Hi I have created a simple standalone chat program by using eclipse rcp. Is there any way that eclipse rcp chat program to migrate to eclipse rap application.
I tried to use the same functionlity in eclipse rap also. It is not working. Anyway to do some kind of socket programming in eclipse rap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Running RCP applications on the web is what many people use RAP for. Your problem description is not very concrete. Your chat client's network communication should not have to differ from the RCP application.

Maybe the [RAP developer's guide](http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/) gets you starting.